# Postgres: ASCII Equivalent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an encoded string: `%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80`

When decoded, this string becomes: `спасо-преображенский собор`

I have tried the following method,
`SELECT convert('%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80', 'SQL_ASCII', 'UTF8')`

But this still gives me the encoded string.
I know it is possible to achieve this because when I do this: `SELECT 'спасо-преображенский собор'` , it gives me the desired result.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: If all characters were encoded the same way, you could use `decode(replace('...', '%', ''), 'hex')` but it seems that `'-'` and `' '` are not encoded in your input string which makes this a bit harder.

Comment: Please specify the encoding. It looks like the string is **rendered** in hexa, but it's not clear what the **encoding** is: UTF-8, ASCII, UTF16, BIG5, etc.?

Comment: @TheImpaler just checked. The database encoding is UTF-8.